# df=df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum() error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

In my data set, I have a list of dates in one column and quantities in another. Some of the dates appear more than once representing different orders made on the same day. I want to find the sum of the quantities ordered on each day, so that each date shows up in the dates column once, with the total number of items purchased that day in the quantity column. I am currently using the df=df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum() function, but it is copying the first sum it finds into any of the following rows with quantities >0. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('stackoverflowexample.xlsx')

df=df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum()

df.to_csv("materialrows.csv")

df=pd.read_csv("materialrows.csv")

array = np.zeros((11,2))

j=0
for i in df['Dates']:
     array[i][0] = i
    array[i][1] = df['OrderQuantity'][j]
    j+1

for i in range(1,15):
    if array[i][0] == 0:
        array[i][0] = array[i-1][0] + 1
    
x=pd.DataFrame(data = array, columns = ["Dates","OrderQuantity"])   

x=x.iloc[1:, :]
x=x['OrderQuantity']
print(x)

df=df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum()
df.to_csv("materialrows.csv")

df=pd.read_csv("materialrows.csv")

array = np.zeros((11,2))

j=0
for i in df['Dates']:
    array[i][0] = i
    array[i][1] = df['OrderQuantity'][j]
    j+1

    for i in range(1,15):
    if array[i][0] == 0:
        array[i][0] = array[i-1][0] + 1
        
y=pd.DataFrame(data = array, columns = ["Dates","OrderQuantity"])   
  
y=y.iloc[1:, :]

y=y['OrderQuantity']

print(y)
```

Here is what the 'stackoverflowexample' excel file looks like.

```
Dates OrderQuantity
1     3
1     4
2     3 
3     8
4     1
5     2
6     6 
7     1
7     2
7     5
8     1
9     2
10    2
```

Here is the current result of my code:

```
1    7
2    7
3    7
4    7
5    7
6    7
7    7
8    7
9    7
10   7
```

Here is the result I want:

```
    1    7
    2    3
    3    8
    4    1
    5    2
    6    6
    7    8
    8    1
    9    2
    10   2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't reproduce; `df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum()` produces correct result.

Comment: Can you remove all the extraneous for-loop code and check whether your input is being overwritten?

Comment: This should be one-liner solution -  ```df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum()``` produces right result as @ifly6 said, just remove the unnecessary code

Comment: Not related to what you've asked, but `j+1` lines don't do anything to `j`. It should be `j+=1` or `j = j + 1`

Answer (score -1):

This `df=df.groupby('Dates')['OrderQuantity'].sum()` returns a series.
Adding the as_index=False field will return a DF -->

```
df = df.groupby('Dates',as_index=False)['OrderQuantity'].sum().
```

Try re-running the cells in your notebook.

Comment: Question doesn't have to do with returning a series or data frame, it has to do with the values being created by a group by.